# Copy file from docker image to jenkins workspace

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkinsfile that uses a dockerfile - and am interested in how I can copy a file from the docker image to the jenkins workspace. Specifically - I am generating an HTML report on the docker image that I'd like to have published by the jenkins job.

For example, if I generate a file called `test.html` in the `/app/` directory of the docker image - how do I copy it to the jenkins workspace so I can publish it.

Sample `Jenkinsfile` below:

```
node ('ondemand') {
    try {
        stage "build"
        checkout scm
        def customImage = docker.build("docker-image:${env.BUILD_ID}", "-f ./docker-image/Dockerfile .")

        stage "test copying files"
        customImage.inside('-u root') {
            sh 'touch /app/test.html && ls' // can see that test.html is generated

        }
    }
```

Comment: Jenkins is going to handle the creation and closing of the container with `inside`. An easy way would be to just copy files from `/app` to somewhere local to your `WORKSPACE`, like `sh "mkdir ${env.WORKSPACE}/jenkinsOut && cp -r /app/ ${env.WORKSPACE}/jenkinsOut"` since the workspace is shared between the container and the host.

Answer (score 15):

As `docker cp` is not supported in docker plugin for pipeline, there are two ways to do it.

**Solution 1** : volume mapping `-v` when starting instance

```
customImage.inside('-v $WORKSPACE:/output -u root') {
    sh 'touch /app/test.html && ls' // can see that test.html is generated
}
archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.html'
```

see complete [Jenkinsfile](https://github.com/larrycai/dockerfile-examples/blob/master/Jenkinsfile)

**Solution 2:** Use traditional docker command in shell (not verified)

```
sh """
docker run --name sample -d -u root docker-image:${env.BUILD_ID} 'touch /app/test.html'
docker cp sample:/app/test.html .
docker rm -f sample
"""
```

Comment: I wonder if people voted for solution one... or solution two, or solution two too

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to bind the workspace folder to the container using docker volume option (`-v /path/build:/app/build`)

Example:

```
node ('ondemand') {
    try {
        stage "build"
        checkout scm
        def customImage = docker.build("docker-image:${env.BUILD_ID}", "-f ./docker-image/Dockerfile .")

        stage "test copying files"
        customImage.inside('-u root -v /path/build:/app/build') {
            sh 'touch /app/build/test.html'
        }
    }
```